# Program terminates starting thread after accept()

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

So I'm trying to build a server which accepts connections on a socket then creates a thread around executing a function which uses the newly opened file descriptor of the accepted connection. The problem I'm having is that when I start the thread, the server goes back to accept another connection (if there is one) but it doesn't block? it seems to be returning from the loop and I don't know why it's doing that. The code being run is:

```
listen(sockfd,10);
int i = 0;
for(;;)
{
    std::cout << "Before accept" << endl;
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    std::cout << "After accept" << endl;

    if (newsockfd < 0)
    {
        std::cout << newsockfd << ": Error on accept" << endl;
        continue;
    }
    else
        std::cout << newsockfd << ": Connection accepted!" << endl;

    boost::thread(boost::bind(&Class::FunctionToRun, this, newsockfd)).start_thread();
    std::cout << ++i << endl;
}
```

The output to toe console is:

```
Socket opened! fd = 3
Before accept
After accept
4: Connection accepted!
1
Before accept
[program terminates]
```

But if accept blocks while waiting for a new connection on the socket, then how come the program terminates before 'After accept' is printed?

Comment: Did the process crash?

Comment: Don't you *want* it to go back and `accept()` again? When you say "terminates", who terminates it? You kill it, or it dies on its own?

Comment: @BrianWalker I don't think so. The process running in it's own thread should be fine. If something happens in the thread that doesn't go as expected, can it terminate the rest of the program?

Comment: @Barry I do want it to accept again! I'm not terminating the program though, it's doing it on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are destroying your thread instantly without joining it:

```
    boost::thread(boost::bind(&Class::FunctionToRun, this, newsockfd)).start_thread();
    // already dead here
    std::cout << ++i << endl;
}
```

If you want your threads to hang around, you need to store them somewhere:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<boost::thread>> threads;
for (;;) {
    // ...
    threads.emplace_back(new boost::thread(boost::bind(...)));
    // thread is still alive here
    std::cout << ++i << endl;
}
```

If not C++11, then you can make it a `vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>>` to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I don't want my threads to hang around. I want them to start as soon as possible.

Comment: @Stapps They will start as soon as you create them - you just need the *object* to hang around, otherwise it will get destroyed... and you don't want it to get destroyed until you're done.

Comment: Your code seems to work but regardless, I'm still have issues with accept() after I add the thread to a list (I had to use push_back since it's pre-C++11). So accept is still terminating the program before it can accept another connection.

Comment: @Stapps Edited my answer to clarify the pre-C++11 solution, I'm assuming you're doing `vector<thread>`? It's not accept that is terminating your program - accept doesn't crash on failure. It's your thread dying in a bad state.

Comment: You're right! my thread was ending in a bad state. It turns out I was calling strcpy() inside my thread which caused it to crash (I'm not sure exactly why that is though...) so I changed a few lines and my threads are working fine now! thanks for your help!